# Setting Conditional Format to reference a UDF works in Excel but not setting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a UDF that highlights the cell header if the column is filtered:

```
Function Is_Col_Filtered(Header As Range) As Boolean

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    
    Set wsh = Header.Parent
    Is_Col_Filtered = wsh.AutoFilter.Filters(Header.Column).On
    
End Function
```

I am trying to execute the following Macro:

```
Sub Macro3()
    
    Dim ws_this As Worksheet
    Dim rng_this As Range
    Dim Msg As String
    
    On Error GoTo Error_Exit
    
        Set ws_this = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2022.07.18")
        Set rng_this = ws_this.Range("A1:O1")
       
        With rng_this
            .Select
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Is_Col_Filtered(A1)"
            .FormatConditions(rng_this.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 49407
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    
Error_Exit:
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) _
         & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
     End If
         
     Set ws_this = Nothing
     Set rng_this = Nothing
         
End Sub
```

The Conditional formatting works correctly when I add it manually, but the macro does not add the conditional formatting formula.  Debugging, it aborts on the Add statement.  The error trap is never triggered.

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: 1.`Set wsh = ActiveSheet` should be `Set wsh = Header.Parent` just to make sure that it does not change if you have another workbook open and active.  2. replace all the `Selection` in your sub code with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TheWorksheetName").Range("A1:O1")`  My guess is that it is not correctly choosing the correct sheet.  Making sure to change the `"TheWorksheetName"` to the correct worksheet name.

Comment: @Scott Craner - Thank you, but it is not working for me still.  I tried to incorporate your suggestions and updated by code above.  At first, I literally did the replace, but when it didn't work, I changed it to use a variable for the sheet and the range so I could read it more easily to be sure I didn't miss a place.  It doesn't even trigger the error condition, it just stops executing at the FormatCondtions.Add.  Even though I rebooted this morning, it must still be something in my environment I guess.